# Connection string format for Oracle 19c database with secondary server

Tags: oracle, load-balancing, oracle19c

We are planning to use complete connectionString of an Oracle database as a secret stored in the key vault and use this in our Linked Service.

I followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory) to get this understanding.

Original connection string:

```
Host=<host>;Port=<port>;ServiceName=<servicename>;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;EncryptionMethod=1;TrustStore=C:\\MyTrustStoreFile;TrustStorePassword=<trust_store_password>
```

OR

```
Host=<host>;Port=<port>;Sid=<sid>;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;EncryptionMethod=1;TrustStore=C:\\MyTrustStoreFile;TrustStorePassword=<trust_store_password>
```

Question : Will the connection string with secondary servers be:

```
Host=<host>;Port=<port>;ServiceName=<servicename>;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;EncryptionMethod=1;TrustStore=C:\\MyTrustStoreFile;TrustStorePassword=<trust_store_password>;AlternateServers=(HostName=<secondary host>:PortNumber=<secondary port>:ServiceName=<secondary service name>)
```